# Bot detection method for MMORPG server

Tags: bots

It's well known that botting is one of the most great thread for MMORPG games. Since it's releatively easy to detect clint injection, I wonder how can MMORPG detect botting from server side. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading some papers, I figure this question by myself.

Here are two kind of major bot detection methods: detected by Sufficient Condition and detected by Necessary Condition.

For Sufficient Condition, it's always useful to detect behavioral action or social action.

For Necessary Condition, it's usually useful to detect Transaction Network Analysis.